# extract number in string using regex

Tags: r, regex

I have a data.frame like this :
`SO <- data.frame(coiffure_IDF$SIREN, coiffure_IDF$L6_NORMALISEE )`

```
  coiffure_IDF.SIREN    coiffure_IDF.L6_NORMALISEE

1 54805015            75008 PARIS

2 300086907           94210 ST MAUR DES FOSSES

3 300090453           94220 CHARENTON LE PONT

4 300209608           75007 PARIS

5 300570553           95880 ENGHIEN LES BAINS

6 301123626           75019 PARIS

7 301362349           92300 LEVALLOIS PERRET
```

I want to have this :

```
  coiffure_IDF.SIREN    codpos_norm     ville

1 54805015            75008             PARIS

2 300086907           94210           ST MAUR DES FOSSES

3 300090453           94220           CHARENTON LE PONT

4 300209608           75007            PARIS

5 300570553           95880            ENGHIEN LES BAINS

6 301123626           75019             PARIS

7 301362349           92300             LEVALLOIS PERRET
```

so I used regex :
`SO2<- SO %>% extract(col="coiffure_IDF.L6_NORMALISEE",                         into=c("codpos_norm", "ville"), regex="(\\d+)\\s+(\\S+)")`

so I have the right column is "codpos_norm" but in "ville" in line 2 I just have "ST" in stead of "ST MAUR DES FOSSES". In line 3 just "CHARENTON", etc
so I tried to add some `\\s+` and `\\S+` in the regex but R told me that they are to many groups and that it has to have only 2 groups.

What could I do ?

Comment: Do you mean you need `regex="(\\d+)\\s+(.+)"`? `.+` will extract any 1 or more chars. Or `.*` if empty values are expected.

Comment: Yes, it works, I didn't know about it.

Comment: post your data as result of `dput(SO)`

Comment: you can easily solve this with `data.table::tstrplit()` but since I have no data to work with i can't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the rest of the string in Group 2, the `\S` construct only matches non-whitespace chars. Use `.+` to match any 1+ chars up to the string end:

```
extract(col="coiffure_IDF.L6_NORMALISEE", into=c("codpos_norm", "ville"), regex="(\\d+)\\s+(.+)")
```

You may use `.*` to match empty strings (if there is no text after 1+ whitespaces).